# SVN for tracking game server changes

Tags: git, svn

As one of the administrators for a DayZ server I have been looking for a way to keep track of changes made by other admins as well as myself. Would SVN be a good choice for this? The server would have to "self host" its own repository. Here are some of my concerns.

1) Would SVN prevent the game server from modifying any files it needs to as part of it's normal operation?

2) Would there be a better choice, such as GIT?

Our purpose in doing this is to be able to roll back changes in case one of the admins makes a mistake in editing a file. Thank you.

Comment: svn cannot prevent anything `from modifying any files`. Peoples change files, svn just show you what and when was changed.

Comment: So SVN does not make the files read only? I was thinking this is how it forced users to 'check out' files before changing them.

Comment: Unlike some older systems, Subversion doesn't make files read-only. (Neither does Git or any other modern source control system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Would SVN prevent the game server from modifying any files it needs to as part of it's normal operation?

No, but you might end up wasting too much space in the repository if you don't ignore changes made by the server and it makes lots of changes.

Especially database files! Database files should not be version controlled with a VCS, unless you have plenty of disk space and you really want to keep all old versions, and even then it might not work.

> 2) Would there be a better choice, such as GIT?

From the information you have provided I don't see any particular reason to use git, however I don't see any particular reason not to use git either, unless you have large files - SVN handles large files very well; git, not so much.